# How to prevent import.sql being executed in Spring Boot unit test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an import.sql file with a few INSERT statements in my classpath. When running my application with profile=devel it's data is being loaded into a postgres db, which is OK so far.

When executing tests with the test profile import.sql is also being triggered for import which leads to "table not found" exceptions. Not sure what the reason is here, but I don't want to use that data for tests anyway.

How can I stop this? Setting hibernate.ddl-auto=none for the test profile does not seem to be a solution as it prevents generation of the schema as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found a solution that fits me better:

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html it is possible to provide a data.sql file that inits the DB with data. Usually this would be picked up in every profile and thus populate a test or production environment with the given testdata - Not so nice!

To prevent this I renamed it to populate_db.sql and set `spring.datasource.data=populate_db.sql` only for the devel profile.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, renaming so will not execute the file in dev mode either, which will be needed to run

Comment: @MohammedRafeeq that's not true. You can use profiles to properly configure `spring.datasource.data` for each environment.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know, you can't configure it. The `import.sql` file is automatically invoked by Hibernate as soon as you use `create-drop` or `create` mode. This is also mentioned by [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) and has nothing to do with Spring:

> In addition, a file named `import.sql` in the root of the classpath is executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that is, if the `ddl-auto` property is set to `create` or `create-drop`).

My guess is that you still want to keep generating your tables in your test scenarios. In that case, you probably want to switch to Spring boot's datasource initialization, by adding a file called `schema.sql` and `data.sql` on the classpath.

This file will be picked automatically on startup by Spring boot (only for embedded datasources in Spring boot 2.0), which is also mentioned by the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html):

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and initialize it (DML scripts). It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: `schema.sql` and `data.sql`, respectively.

Now, to be able to disable loading data during your test phase, you can work with profiles. For example, with Spring boot 2.x you can disable this by using the following property:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never # Property for Spring boot 2.0
spring.datasource.initialize=false # Property for Spring boot 1.0
```

**Be aware**, this disables both the schema creation, and the data loading SQL files. Disabling only the `data.sql` file is not possible, but can be achieved by using a simple trick by renaming the default filename that Spring boot will look for:

```
spring.datasource.data=somethingelse.sql
```

If you only configure this property during your tests, Spring boot will look for a file called `somethingelse.sql`, and won't pick up your `data.sql` file. While when running with the dev profile, you discard this property, and Spring boot will look for (and find) `data.sql`.

---

An alternative approach that works for both Spring boot's `schema.sql`/`data.sql` and Hibernate's `import.sql` is to work with Maven profiles and to load different classpath folders when running tests. However, I wouldn't recommend doing so, because it makes running tests in IDEs a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an empty "import.sql" file in the "/resources" folder under your "test" folder, e.g. "src/test/resources".
That way, when you run test, hibernate will execute the empty "import.sql" in the "test/resources" folder (instead of executing the actual "import.sql" file in your main folder).