# Prevent import.sql running in the scope of test

Tags: spring-boot, testing

How I can prevent to run import.sql file inside main/resources not deleting or clearing the file in the scope of testing?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class SomeIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

}
```

When I run tests, the import.sql always executed:

```
INFO 16501 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'ScriptSourceInputFromUrl(file:/Users/SomeUser/Projects/PRJ/space/backend/service/someService/out/production/resources/import.sql)'
```

Comment: So do you want to run another .sql file to run your unit test cases?

Comment: No, I don't want to execute any .sql since I don't want to define all data required for different tests. I thought to do data population via repositories. But I don't want to delete import.sql in main/resources file with predefined data since it actually uses when I boot my app not in testing scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent import.sql being executed in Spring Boot unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188207/how-to-prevent-import-sql-being-executed-in-spring-boot-unit-test)

Comment: Agree with 'This does not solve the problem, renaming so will not execute the file in dev mode either, which will be needed to run '

Comment: @user1376885 Whether or not you agree with the accepted answer does not change the fact that this is a 100% duplicate. Feel free to add a bounty to that question to ask for other answers. Besides that, the comment is just plain wrong.